# CSRF & CORS with AngularJS + Laravel

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel, cross-domain, csrf

I'm working on an AngularJS webapp with a Laravel backend.

I want to enable CSRF protection with cross-domain requests. Is it possible?

[$http reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in "Cross Site Request Forgery" says "The header will not be set for cross-domain requests"

Looking the Developer Tools logs I see that after the $http.post call the preflight request is sent (OPTION verb) and it has the XSRF-TOKEN cookies set, but the POST request has no cookies so I can't do:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'];
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

@zeroflagL: I tried with

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.xsrfCookieName = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
$http.defaults.headers.common.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
```

And now in the Request headers of the POST I have:

```
xsrfCookieName:XSRF-TOKEN
xsrfHeaderName:X-XSRF-TOKEN
```

But the CSRF check is not passed (TokenMismatchException on the server).
I suppose that in the Request headers there should be the XSRF-TOKEN to work...

Comment: Did you set `xsrfHeaderName` and `xsrfCookieName` as said in the documentation?

Comment: @zeroflagL: I tried without success, updated my post

Comment: Remove `headers.common.` It's just `$http.defaults.xsrf...`.

Comment: It should be correct with `$http.defaults.headers.common.xsrf...`, if I use your form nothing is set in the POST request headers.
BTW this doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: I just realized that you want to send the header for cross-domain requests. That doesn't make any sense. XSRF affects **your** site.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? For completeness I'm creating a Ionic app, so client and server are on different domains. I would like to prevent XSRF attacks. Currently I disabled the check on the server otherwise I can't do POSTs requests

Comment: Example: You have a website `http://myweb.com`. The user is logged in. The user opens the site `http://evil.com` in another tab. That evil site embeds an image tag having the URL `http://myweb.com/transferMoney`. Because the user is still logged in, the session id is sent and the request seems ok from the servers perspective. If the client runs on the `http://anotherweb.com` and makes a Cross-Site request to `http://myweb.com` then XSRF isn't an issue because the request doesn't appear to come from your site anyway.

Comment: Aw, you are right. I thought that XSRF was different. If you post your comment as reply I close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As zeroflagL said CSRF protection can't be applied to cross domain requests.

To reply to my question: no, it's not possible.